# jQuery Hover Events not Firing on UL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have looked through the plethora of questions with similar titles and can't, for the life of me, figure out what's happening. I have a system using KnockoutJS + jQuery that will populate a list and add a class to a hovered list that will highlight it on a map in another function.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: markers" class="locationListMain">
    <ul class="locationList">
        <h3 class="resultTITLE">
          <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        </h3>
        <p class="resultLATLONG">
          LAT
          <span data-bind="text: lat"></span>
          , LONG 
          <span data-bind="text: lng"></span>
        </p>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Simple enough. Now I'm trying to call a hover event on `.locationList` like so via jQuery:

```
$('.locationList').hover(function(){
  console.log('hovering');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}, function() {
  console.log('not hovering!');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

But I can't get anything to fire. The weird thing is, if I remove the `.locationList` element, and add that class to the top level `<ul>`, it works without a problem. I'm wondering if it's a CSS problem, but I can't nail that down either. Have moved it to top z index with no joy. Thoughts? Would greatly appreciate any help or insight. Thanks!

Comment: That probably means that you’re binding the hover event listener to `.locationList` before it is available in the DOM at runtime. When your JS is executed and the element is not available yet, then you’re binding the hover event to an empty set returned by the selector. You should either execute this binding when the element is rendered, or make use of event bubbling (ie `$someParent.on('mouseenter', '.locationList', function(){...})`) on a parent node that is present at runtime.

Comment: Moving this function under $(document).ready did the trick. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Terry's comment, figured it out. The hover event listener was trying to bind to the element before it was available in the dom. Moving the hover function under

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

did the trick.